# Clean more pythonic way to loop over nested keys that don't always exist

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested, key

I'm trying to clean up this code.

For example

```
data = [
{
    "version": "11g",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "build_number": "11.2.0.4.0",
    "path": "",
    "devices": [
      {
        "host_name": "server1",
        "manufacturer": "HP",
      },
      {
        "host_name": "server2",
        "manufacturer": "HP",
      }
    ]
},
{
    "version": "11g",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "build_number": "11.2.0.4.0",
    "path": "",
}
]

for each in data:
    version = each["version"]
    if "devices" in each:
        for server in each["devices"]:
            hostname = server["host_name"]
            print(version, hostname)
    else:
        hostname = None
        print(version, hostname)
```

This prints out the following which is what I want. Is there a way to do it without using two print statements?

11g server1

11g server2

12g None

Comment: You ask: "Is there a way to do it without using two print statements?". Do you really want to print without print statements? Or do you mean print without the loop? Or don't you mind the loop but you just want one print statement instead of 2?

Answer (score 0):

### Null Object (1 `print`)

If you want to print `(version, None)` for `each` without `"devices"`, then something like this slould do:

```
for each in data:
    version = each["version"]
    for server in each.get("devices", [{"host_name": None}]):
        hostname = server["host_name"]
        print(version, hostname)
```

Explanation: if `each` doesn't have `"devices"`, `get()` with return a list with one fake device (`[{"host_name": None}]`), with a hostname that you want to print when there's no device.

For readability, I would save that fake device to a named constant:

```
NONE_DEVICE = {"host_name": None}
for each in data:
    version = each["version"]
    for server in each.get("devices", [NONE_DEVICE]):
        hostname = server["host_name"]
        print(version, hostname)
```

This is similar to "Null Object" design pattern, where you return a special "empty" object when there is no object.

### My solution (2 `print`s)

However, it's debatable whether it's appropriate to fake missing devices with some special object instead of just admitting that there's no devices. I personally wouldn't get rid of the `if` statement and the second `print`. I would clean up this code in a different area:

```
# `server` is renamed to `device`,
# so that the same thing doesn't have two different names.
# I'd also change `each` to something meaningful.
for each in data:
    if "devices" not in each:
        print(each["version"], None)
        continue
    for device in each["devices"]:
        print(each["version"], device["host_name"])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using get()? I'm thinking about trying to use a if "devices" not in each than assign a default variable.

Comment: I was editing my answer as you commented this, actually `if "devices" not in each` is exactly what I prefer

Comment: Same. It still throws a key error though.

Comment: You're right, I've overlooked this. `if` needs to be on top, with added `continue` inside

Comment: Thank you! I like this solution the best. Especially as I know I will have more nested keys deeper inside the devices list/dict that may contain other data. Also the not in makes it more readable.

Comment: Yes, it's actually a good rule of thumb to handle such special cases in an `if` statement at the top, put `return`/`continue` there, and then write "happy path" logic below, unindented and uncluttered. I first head about this in some "why I don't use `else`" video

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use list comprehensions. Shorter but less readable.
Lets start with the simple case: print version if no device present:

```
[print(row['version']) for row in data if 'devices' not in row]
```

But with the nested list comprehension things get less readable:

```
[print(row['version'], [device['host_name'] for device in row['devices']]) for row in data if 'devices' in row]
```